# How to draw such a picture(in ascii character, -+>)?

Tags: emacs, drawing

[image]
Is it drawn by emacs? `+----+` seems like lines of table generated by emacs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\
|                      |

|  I draw them by hand |

|                      |
+----------------------+ <- depends on what you want here
```